# Error while installing postgreSQL "cluster initialisation failed"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

**The setup:**
Windows 10, postgreSQL 12.3, all the values are default.

**The problem:**
While installing postgresql 12.3 I get an error message at the end of the installation: "problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed"
When I then try to run the SQL shell (through the start menu), and I press enter to default all the values, it gives me a connection refused error.

When uninstalling postgreSQL, I also get an error message: "Error deleting service postgresql-x64- 12" two times.

**What I tried:**

1. installing postgreSQL in a directory C:\postgresql (as opposed to in the Program files)
2. There was no service related to postgreSQL, so I added it manually with this commandline (openened cmd as admin in the postgresql bin directory)

`pg_ctl.exe register -N "PostgreSQL" -U "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"-D "C:/Program Files/postgresql/pgsql/bin/pgsql/data" -w`

3. Uninstalling/Reinstalling postgresql, rebooting the PC
4. Disabling all firewalls
5. Checking that the COMSPEC environement variable is valid with `echo %COMSPEC%`and `"%COMSPEC%" /C "echo test ok"`
6. Ran regedit, went to the registry entry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services", there was a postgreSQL service (after adding it manually)